# .htaccess Redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Im using Apache and an .htaccess file to set up some redirects. Is there a way to 301 redirect everything in a domain to a subdomain *except* for the domain index?

So redirect `http://domain.com/*` to `http://sub.domain.com/*`

But leave `http://domain.com/` where it is?

Thanks in advance if anybody is able to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single rewrite rule:

```
# Rewrite if on main domain AND NOT requesting index
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain[.]com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/(index[.](html|php))?)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.%1$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Comment: This looks like it should do the job in the most succinct way - I will test once the new domain.com page is built and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: I have finally gotten around to needing this and have tested it out. It seems to be close to what I need, but it is also rewriting css and javascript requests for the main (non-redirected) page. Is there a way to also exclude *.css and *.js from the redirect?

Comment: @mrappleton - I've added a couple of conditions to the rewrite above - it will not rewrite if the file exists...

Answer (score 0):

```
# Check for non-empty request URI
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)
RewriteRule .* http://sub.domain.com%1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to allow for default html or php on your main domain.  In that case, the following pair of rules should work.  Test and confirm.

```
# Skip the rewrite for the root of domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain[.]com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/(index[.](html|php))?)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L]

# Rewrite everything else 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(domain[.]com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.%1$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```